# Angular google map fill space

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use an Angular Google Map inside of a web application that is using Bootstrap for styling. Right now I am just trying to get a basic example working that shows a webpage consisting of a navigation bar and a google map (using Angular's `ui-gmap-google-map` element) that takes up all of the remaining space. However, I cannot get the Google Map to have anything other than a fixed height that does not account for the sizes of other elements on the screen.

Below is my code:

**mapSandbox.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
            BRAND GOES HERE
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- 'container-fluid' was an attempt to make the division use the full width -->
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">

    <!-- THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO FILL THE REMAINING SPACE -->
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" control="map.control"></ui-gmap-google-map>

    <h1>Other content here</h1>

</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
<script src="js/mapSandbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/mapSandbox.js**

```
// Initialize angular
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
})
.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
      uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
          key: '{KEY IS HERE}',
          v: '3.22',
          libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
      });
});
```

**css/style.css**

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I am aware that this is a *really* common question; however, none of the proposed fixes that I have work. I have looked at the following solutions and address my problem:

- The [official Angular tutorial](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use) indicates that something like `.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }` should be used. This is not what I want as this is a fixed size and does not fill the remaining space.
- Using `.angular-google-map-container { height: 100vh; }` is close except it does not take into account anything else that is already there (like the navigation bar). As a result the entire page length becomes 100% of view height + the height of all other items (which results in a scroll bar).
- Using `.angular-google-map-container { height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }`  (see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/287)) was the closest I got and *looks* like it does the right thing. **However,** under closer inspection it is clear that something is really screwed up and this is just a hack. For example, Chrome's inspection tools show that the divisions that contain the `.angular-google-map-container` (e.g. `#main`) have zero height even though their child (the map element in question) is huge. Also, the map takes up the entire webpage (the navbar appears to be given a z order that puts it on top of the map) instead of just taking up the remaining space.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I find myself banging my head against everything in sight whenever I have to do any CSS work. Doing something similar with Swing, Android, etc. is so trivially easy that I would expect that there is a similarly easy way to do this here.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nozive/edit?html,js,output) is a test for this.

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin or [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/) for this?

Comment: Added (but broken)

Comment: I did it for you.. http://jsbin.com/nozive/edit?html,js,output (Why did you include **angular2** instead og **angularJS**? never mind.. You can update your question) What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the fix. My problem is that (as stated in the my post), I cannot get the map to fill the remaining space, i.e. I do not want to have a fixed size for the height of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve is by set the `#main`'s `position` to `absolute` as the following code:

P.S. The one thing with a fix size is the `top` which is OK because the `nav`'s height is fix in any resolution.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.map = { 
    center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 
  };
})
.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  //uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
  //    key: '{KEY IS HERE}',
  //    v: '3.22',
  //    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  //});
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main {
  /*position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  top:51px;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  position:relative;
}

ui-gmap-google-map, .angular-google-map,.angular-google-map-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="4.11.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/angular-simple-logger.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-google-maps@*" data-semver="2.0.11" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/master/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
            BRAND GOES HERE
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- 'container-fluid' was an attempt to make the division use the full width -->
    <h1>Other content here</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <!-- THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO FILL THE REMAINING SPACE -->
      <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" control="map.control"></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/nozive/4/edit?html,css,js

Comment: What limits the nav height so that the fixed top pixel for the map will always work?

Comment: This is so close; however, it still is not working. Once I add any other element to the #main division, scrollbars appear (see my updated question).

Comment: @curob What you want to happen in this situation?

Comment: I would like the new element (say "<h1>TEST</h1>") take up its normal amount of space and the map to take up the remaining space without having scroll bars but also not leaving any free space.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I've accomplished what I need with this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#map-canvas {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}


<div id="map-canvas">
    <ui-gmap-google-map></ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work (for some reason). The map still has 0 height when I use that in my code.

Comment: Sorry, it's been awhile since I have messed with this, you can manipulate the underlying css for the ui-gmap directive.